# Angular routerlink not navigating

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I have a material sidenav that I am trying to link up using routerlink. However, the links are not navigating. They are not clickable at all. They react accordingly when I manually go the corresponding route since their routerLinkActive css is being activated.

I am trying to put the routes onto a div which contains an SVG image.

I have tried the links on a normal a tag just to see if it had something to do with the SVG implementation. I am pretty sure all the children routes and all are correctly implemented as well.

**My HMTL**

```
<mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" class="mat-elevation-z6">
      <div class="side-nav-btns">
        <div class="item" 
            [routerLink]="['./dashboard']" 
            [routerLinkActive]="['active-nav-btn']">
            <svg-icon class="side-nav-btn" [applyCss]="true" src="../../assets/dashboard.svg"></svg-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="item" 
            [routerLink]="['./bot']" 
            [routerLinkActive]="['active-nav-btn']">
            <svg-icon class="side-nav-btn" [applyCss]="true" src="../../assets/circuit.svg"></svg-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="item"
             [routerLink]="['./lobby']"
             [routerLinkActive]="['active-nav-btn']">
          <svg-icon class="side-nav-btn" [applyCss]="true" src="../../assets/poker-table.svg"></svg-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="item"
             [routerLink]="['./tournament']"
             [routerLinkActive]="['active-nav-btn']">
          <svg-icon class="side-nav-btn" [applyCss]="true" src="../../assets/tournament.svg"></svg-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

**My Component Routes**

```
const platformRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: PlatformComponent, children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: 'bot', component: BotComponent},
      {path: 'lobby', component: LobbyComponent},
      {path: 'tournament', component: TournamentComponent}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(platformRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PlatformRoutingModule {
}
```

**My Root Routes**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'landing-pages'},
  {path: 'landing-pages', loadChildren: './landing-pages/landing-pages.module#LandingPagesModule'},
  {path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
  {path: 'platform', loadChildren: './platform/platform.module#PlatformModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, useHash: true})
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I included all children components in the platform module.

I expect it to navigate to the corresponding route when I click one of the icons, however, I currently can't click them.

Answer (score 0):

DIVs are not actionable elements, try using anchor tags, for example:

```
<a class="item" [routerLink]="['./dashboard']" [routerLinkActive]="['active-nav-btn']">
  <svg-icon class="side-nav-btn" [applyCss]="true" src="../../assets/dashboard.svg"></svg-icon>
</a>
```

Comment: I tried that and was still not able to navigate. Not sure If I am somehow declaring my paths incorrectly, but I don't think so.

Comment: Have you tested your routes? I mean not by clicking the button but by typing in the search bar `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` (for example)

Comment: Yes, and they successfully load, as well as the routerLinkActive successfully being activated for the corresponding div.

Comment: I  have also tried just <a> tag with no div or SVG, but am still not able to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. It had to do with css funny enough. I had set the sidenav to have a z-index of -1 since I am also using a toolbar and it was covering the shadow.

This however made it so I could not interact with anything in the sidenav, (makes sense), so I just changed the z-index and got it working.